# Word that means making opposites agree

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a single word that means making two (or more) seemingly opposite or contradictory words/ideas/concepts agree with each other. Or at least work together.

I'm 90% the word starts with a C, but I can't think of it. It's a very formal sounding word that one might expect to see in the title of thesis or something.

An example would be, "On the ____ of idea x and idea y".

Comment: Arbitrate, mediate, conciliate, reconcile, referee, compromise, harmonize, accommodate.

Comment: maybe you are thinking of "On the contrary ..." This is an upper class, neutral way of beginning a sentence indicating disagreement. It doesn't make opposites agree, but it is (normally) polite, as it aims to intellectualize (and hence de-emotionalize) the argument.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're looking for [reconcile](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/reconcile?s=t):

> 3. to bring into agreement or harmony; make compatible or consistent

*On the reconciliation of science and religion.*

Answer (score 0):

Consider *synthesis*:

> **synthesis** *noun*
>   1 The combination of components or elements to form a connected whole.
>   ‘the synthesis of intellect and emotion in his work’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/synthesis)

The notion of reconciling *opposites* might come from definition 3, about *Hegelian* synthesis:

> 3 (in Hegelian philosophy) the final stage in the process of dialectical reasoning, in which a new idea resolves the conflict between thesis and antithesis.